# Threshold value for sigmoid nonlinearity for multilabel classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use the [DenseNet architecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf) to classify x-ray images from https://www.kaggle.com/nih-chest-xrays/data. The model produces a vector of binary labels, where each label indicates the presence or absence of 14 possible pathologies:  Atelectasis, Cardiomegaly, Consolidation, Edema, Effusion,
Emphysema, Fibrosis, Hernia, Infiltration, Mass, Nodule, Pleural Thickening, Pneumonia, and Pneumothorax. For example, a healthy patient would have a label of [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], while a patient with edema and effusion would have a label of [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]. I built this model with tensorflow, and since this is a multi-label classification problem, the cost function that I used was tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(labels, logits)), which is minimized with the AdamOptimizer. However, when I inspected the sigmoid output, the values are all below 0.5, resulting in tf.round(logits) to produce zeros for every prediction. The actual logits are different for different input, and are non-zero values after 10000 iterations, so I don't think vanishing gradients is the problem. I have two questions:

1. Could this problem be caused by an incorrect implementation of the model?
2. Would I be "cheating" if I reduce the threshold value for the sigmoid function to 0.25 from 0.5 to improve model accuracy?

Thanks.

Here's the code for the model:

```
def DenseNet(features, labels, mode, params):

depth = params["depth"]
k = params["growth"]

if depth == 121:
    N = db_121
else:
    N = db_169

bottleneck_output = 4 * k

#before entering the first dense block, a conv operation with 16 output channels
#is performed on the input images

with tf.variable_scope('input_layer'):
    #l = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 224, 224, 1])
    feature_maps = 2 * k
    l = layers.conv(features, filter_size = 7, stride = 2, out_chn = feature_maps)
    l = tf.nn.max_pool(l,
                       padding='SAME',
                       ksize=[1,3,3,1],
                       strides=[1,2,2,1],
                       name='max_pool')

# each block is defined as a dense block + transition layer
with tf.variable_scope('block1'):
    for i in range(N[0]):
        with tf.variable_scope('bottleneck_layer.{}'.format(i+1)):
            bn_l = layers.batch_norm('BN', l)
            bn_l = tf.nn.relu(bn_l, name='relu')
            bn_l = layers.conv(bn_l, out_chn=bottleneck_output, filter_size=1)
        l = layers.add_layer('dense_layer.{}'.format(i+1), l, bn_l)
    l = layers.transition_layer('transition1', l)

with tf.variable_scope('block2'):
    for i in range(N[1]):
        with tf.variable_scope('bottleneck_layer.{}'.format(i+1)):
            bn_l = layers.batch_norm('BN', l)
            bn_l = tf.nn.relu(bn_l, name='relu')
            bn_l = layers.conv(bn_l, out_chn=bottleneck_output, filter_size=1)
        l = layers.add_layer('dense_layer.{}'.format(i+1), l, bn_l)
    l = layers.transition_layer('transition2', l)

with tf.variable_scope('block3'):
    for i in range(N[2]):
        with tf.variable_scope('bottleneck_layer.{}'.format(i+1)):
            bn_l = layers.batch_norm('BN', l)
            bn_l = tf.nn.relu(bn_l, name='relu')
            bn_l = layers.conv(bn_l, out_chn=bottleneck_output, filter_size=1)
        l = layers.add_layer('dense_layer.{}'.format(i+1), l, bn_l)
    l = layers.transition_layer('transition3', l)

# the last block does not have a transition layer
with tf.variable_scope('block4'):
    for i in range(N[3]):
        with tf.variable_scope('bottleneck_layer.{}'.format(i+1)):
            bn_l = layers.batch_norm('BN', l)
            bn_l = tf.nn.relu(bn_l, name='relu')
            bn_l = layers.conv(bn_l, out_chn=bottleneck_output, filter_size=1)
        l = layers.add_layer('dense_layer.{}'.format(i+1), l, bn_l)

# classification (global max pooling and softmax)
with tf.name_scope('classification'):
    l = layers.batch_norm('BN', l)
    l = tf.nn.relu(l, name='relu')
    l = layers.pooling(l, filter_size = 7)
    l_shape = l.get_shape().as_list()
    l = tf.reshape(l, [-1, l_shape[1] * l_shape[2] * l_shape[3]])
    l = tf.layers.dense(l, units = 1000, activation = tf.nn.relu, name='fc1', kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    output = tf.layers.dense(l, units = 14, name='fc2', kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()) # [batch_size, 14]

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=output) # cost function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cost_fn')
```

Comment: I think you are on the right path, but you might be thinking about the problem in the wrong way. Might it be the case that the positives (1s) are way less frequent than the negatives (0s). Based on your loss function, think about what that might drive a softmax layer to do (would it be a better bet, intuitively, to be a model guessing all 1s or all 0s?). I think you are on the right track. Think precision, recall and what you actually want the model to do. Happy to write a full answer if that doesn't lead you in the right direction

Comment: @PeterBarrettBryan Thank you for your suggestions. You are absolutely right:  'No Findings' represent more than half of the dataset, so it makes sense for the model to output 0s (or values closer to 0) to minimize the cost function. So would it be better to optimize a weighted cross entropy loss function? I don't have a stats background so I'm not sure what the best practice is ...

Comment: I think the answer I've provided should guide you in the right direction for a multi label problem of this sort (perhaps complicated by the interrelationships between predicted labels). If it doesn't help, let me know and I am happy to edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theophylline! First, let me repeat the comment I left in case this answer ends up working for you long-term (and perhaps other folks):

> I think you are on the right path, but you might be thinking about the problem in the wrong way. Might it be the case that the positives (1s) are way less frequent than the negatives (0s). Based on your loss function, think about what that might drive a softmax layer to do (would it be a better bet, intuitively, to be a model guessing all 1s or all 0s?). I think you are on the right track. Think precision, recall and what you actually want the model to do. Happy to write a full answer if that doesn't lead you in the right direction

Your question is a little tricky, because I don't know the full background of the relationship between the predicted values (are the predicted categories independent, heavily dependent, etc.) Further, you will have to make a call on the value of precision and recall (do you think a false positive is worse? a false negative? are they equally bad?). I think for an initial pass, it might be worth trying [weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits). You can bias the model to make positive and negative judgments based on the heuristic guiding your precision recall decision (on medical data, I presume a false negative is a *very bad thing*)

This answer is based on a 1000ft view of your problem, so if it doesn't work well for you, happy to revise my answer! If you are looking for pure accuracy (at the expense of precision/recall balance), it might be worth trying to demonstrate that in a training set you can approximate the frequency of the classes in the testing set (and subsequently weight the individual predictions to match). Your thresholding idea is dead on as long as it is implemented carefully (don't share frequency information between train and test, etc.)

EDIT: in case it is not obvious from the documentation, this section will help guide you to build a custom loss function if appropriate!

```
  qz * -log(sigmoid(x)) + (1 - z) * -log(1 - sigmoid(x))
= qz * -log(1 / (1 + exp(-x))) + (1 - z) * -log(exp(-x) / (1 + exp(-x)))
= qz * log(1 + exp(-x)) + (1 - z) * (-log(exp(-x)) + log(1 + exp(-x)))
= qz * log(1 + exp(-x)) + (1 - z) * (x + log(1 + exp(-x))
= (1 - z) * x + (qz +  1 - z) * log(1 + exp(-x))
= (1 - z) * x + (1 + (q - 1) * z) * log(1 + exp(-x))

(1 - z) * x + l * (log(1 + exp(-abs(x))) + max(-x, 0))
```